# How to debug AppCompat TextView InflateException?

Tags: android, textview, android-appcompat

This crash recently came in via our crash reporting system. I cannot reproduce this crash, and to date we only have 1 report.

The application is a large application, with many activities and fragments, and the stacktrace gives no indication of where in the application the crash occurred (The entire stacktrace appears to take place in `Android` or `AppCompat` classes - no mention of my app's code).

So essentially I have no way of knowing which `TextView`, out of 100s of TextViews, in my application is at issue (and no, I cannot post all the layout xml files for my entire application).

Given that information, can anyone offer advice on how to debug this stacktrace?

```
Fatal Exception: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #43: Binary XML file line #43: Error inflating class TextView

Caused by android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #43: Error inflating class TextView

Caused by java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Failed to resolve attribute at index 4: TypedValue{t=0x2/d=0x1010099 a=1}
       at android.content.res.TypedArray.getColor(TypedArray.java:476)
       at android.widget.TextView.<init>(TextView.java:1077)
       at android.widget.TextView.<init>(TextView.java:990)
       at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView.<init>(AppCompatTextView.java:62)
       at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView.<init>(AppCompatTextView.java:58)
       at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater.createView(AppCompatViewInflater.java:103)
       at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.createView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:1029)
       at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.onCreateView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:1087)
       at android.support.v4.view.LayoutInflaterCompatHC$FactoryWrapperHC.onCreateView(LayoutInflaterCompatHC.java:47)
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:776)
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:734)
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:865)
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:828)
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:873)
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:828)
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:873)
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:828)
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:525)
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:427)
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:378)
       at android.widget.Editor$SuggestionsPopupWindow.initContentView(Editor.java:3686)
       at android.widget.Editor$PinnedPopupWindow.<init>(Editor.java:3384)
       at android.widget.Editor$SuggestionsPopupWindow.<init>(Editor.java:3669)
       at android.widget.Editor.replace(Editor.java:423)
       at android.widget.Editor$3.run(Editor.java:2343)
       at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6682)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1520)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1410)
```

Comment: Can you post `SuggestionsPopupWindow`?

Comment: Can u share your .xml

Comment: @Anil no, I cannot share the .xml of my entire application.  I've updated the question to try and make the situation more clear.

Comment: Have u used any custom text view if yes at least you can share that

Comment: @azizbekian SuggestionsPopupWindow is not something I'm creating.  I only have 1 place in my entire codebase that includes "Suggestions", and that's ``setInputType(getInputType() | InputType.TYPE_TEXT_FLAG_NO_SUGGESTIONS | InputType.TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_EMAIL_ADDRESS);``

Comment: Can you verify, that you activity's theme is a descendant of `AppCompat` theme?

Comment: @azizbekian Yes, all my activity's have ``android:theme="@style/AppTheme"``, and that is an AppCompat descendent theme.

@Anil - I have TextViewNoUnderline that extends AppCompatTextView, TextInputAutoCompleteTextView that extends AppCompatAutoCompleteTextView, and ContactChooserEditTextView which extends AppCompatMultiAutoCompleteTextView.  However I can't share the code for these.

Comment: Just curious, what was the OS version of the device this occurred on? I'm getting this crash on a lot of Android 4.4 devices.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are inflating a view in service or with applicaiton context then theme attributes might be unavalable at certain times

Use `context.setTheme(R.style.your_theme);` 
before inflating your view

I was getting same error solved using this.

More on this [ContextThemeWrapper](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ContextThemeWrapper.html)

Comment: Thanks @Rajnish - this is good advice. However views are never inflated in a service or with the application context. The app is on the large side - 350+ classes, with >150k LOC, and >500 ``<TextView>``'s.  The problem wasn't found during testing, and I have no idea how to replicate it.

Comment: I'm seeing another reported crash that's likely related to this:
Fatal Exception: java.lang.IllegalStateException - You need to use a Theme.AppCompat theme (or descendant) with this activity.

Unfortunately the stack trace doesn't tell me the activity it occurs in either (base activity class). My app has a default theme that is a descendent of Theme.AppCompat, and any activities I have defined that use a different theme also use Theme.AppCompat, except for a few third party activities (facebook, zendesk)

Comment: As for as I can decode you are setting textColor (may be in third party lib) by this line  at android.content.res.TypedArray.getColor(TypedArray.java:476) , also investigate if you are inflating any view from these libs. The may be from there..

Comment: Accepted this as the answer.  Debugging this kind of stack trace is really hard - since it's basically impossible to determine where it happens.

Answer (score -2):

The problem was with the Parent theme of the style TextView.
Check id of this textview

Comment: Which TextView?  If I knew which TextView, I'd check it. Problem is the stacktrace gives 0 indication of which TextView results in the crash.